# Parsing data with unusual format in python

Tags: python, parsing

I have this ASCII file that is formatted somewhat oddly where the headers are organized by rows followed the corresponding values and their assoicated error also organized by rows.  A snippet of the file is shown below.

```
f     7523
  10001  10002  10003  10004  10005  10006  10007  10008  10009  10010  10011
  10012  10013  10014  10015  10016  10017  10018  10019  10020  10021  10022
vals
  0.00000E+00 0.0000  7.65079E-12 0.7071  0.00000E+00 0.0000  3.87977E-14 0.5513
  0.00000E+00 0.0000  0.00000E+00 0.0000  0.00000E+00 0.0000  0.00000E+00 0.0000
  0.00000E+00 0.0000  1.92698E-14 0.7071  4.47277E-14 0.7071  0.00000E+00 0.0000
  0.00000E+00 0.0000  0.00000E+00 0.0000  0.00000E+00 0.0000  1.10023E-11 0.7053
  1.74410E-11 0.5005  0.00000E+00 0.0000  1.69181E-13 0.7071  0.00000E+00 0.0000
  0.00000E+00 0.0000  0.00000E+00 0.0000
vals
  1.34313E-06 0.0104  1.32163E-06 0.0102  1.30039E-06 0.0105  1.37575E-06 0.0106
  1.30792E-06 0.0102  1.28351E-06 0.0104  1.32164E-06 0.0102  1.32969E-06 0.0104
  1.31707E-06 0.0104  1.27281E-06 0.0103  1.28429E-06 0.0106  1.27027E-06 0.0105
  1.29623E-06 0.0105  1.32037E-06 0.0101  1.28948E-06 0.0105  1.33163E-06 0.0106
  1.36073E-06 0.0102  1.35462E-06 0.0102  1.38641E-06 0.0102  1.33099E-06 0.0102
  1.35307E-06 0.0100  1.33882E-06 0.0105
```

I want to parse this file so that the data is organized in five separate columns so that it looks something like

```
10001      0.00000E+00 0.0000   1.34313E-06 0.0104
10002      7.65079E-12 0.7071   1.32163E-06 0.0102
10003      0.00000E+00 0.0000   1.30039E-06 0.0105
....
10022      0.00000E+00 0.0000   1.33882E-06 0.0105
```

I am unsure of how to cycle through this data to have the above format however beyond the simple start of it with

```
# Open file
f = open('data.txt', 'r')

# Loop over lines and extract variables of interest
for line in f:
    line = line.strip()
    columns = line.split()
```

Comment: Loop through the lines until you get the next header, putting all the values from each `vars` section into lits. Then you can loop through the lists in parallel with `zip()` and create each line of output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `re` to parse the file into a dataframe:

```py
text = """\
f     7523
  10001  10002  10003  10004  10005  10006  10007  10008  10009  10010  10011
  10012  10013  10014  10015  10016  10017  10018  10019  10020  10021  10022
vals
  0.00000E+00 0.0000  7.65079E-12 0.7071  0.00000E+00 0.0000  3.87977E-14 0.5513
  0.00000E+00 0.0000  0.00000E+00 0.0000  0.00000E+00 0.0000  0.00000E+00 0.0000
  0.00000E+00 0.0000  1.92698E-14 0.7071  4.47277E-14 0.7071  0.00000E+00 0.0000
  0.00000E+00 0.0000  0.00000E+00 0.0000  0.00000E+00 0.0000  1.10023E-11 0.7053
  1.74410E-11 0.5005  0.00000E+00 0.0000  1.69181E-13 0.7071  0.00000E+00 0.0000
  0.00000E+00 0.0000  0.00000E+00 0.0000
vals
  1.34313E-06 0.0104  1.32163E-06 0.0102  1.30039E-06 0.0105  1.37575E-06 0.0106
  1.30792E-06 0.0102  1.28351E-06 0.0104  1.32164E-06 0.0102  1.32969E-06 0.0104
  1.31707E-06 0.0104  1.27281E-06 0.0103  1.28429E-06 0.0106  1.27027E-06 0.0105
  1.29623E-06 0.0105  1.32037E-06 0.0101  1.28948E-06 0.0105  1.33163E-06 0.0106
  1.36073E-06 0.0102  1.35462E-06 0.0102  1.38641E-06 0.0102  1.33099E-06 0.0102
  1.35307E-06 0.0100  1.33882E-06 0.0105
"""

import re
import pandas as pd

data = [
    [c.split() for c in group.split("  ")]
    for _, group in re.findall(r"(^\s+)(.*?)(?=^\S|\Z)", text, flags=re.S | re.M)
]

idx = [h for c in data[0] for h in c]

df = pd.concat(
    [pd.DataFrame(d, index=idx) for d in data[1:]], axis=1
)
df.columns = range(len(df.columns))

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                 0       1            2       3
10001  0.00000E+00  0.0000  1.34313E-06  0.0104
10002  7.65079E-12  0.7071  1.32163E-06  0.0102
10003  0.00000E+00  0.0000  1.30039E-06  0.0105
10004  3.87977E-14  0.5513  1.37575E-06  0.0106
10005  0.00000E+00  0.0000  1.30792E-06  0.0102
10006  0.00000E+00  0.0000  1.28351E-06  0.0104
10007  0.00000E+00  0.0000  1.32164E-06  0.0102
10008  0.00000E+00  0.0000  1.32969E-06  0.0104
10009  0.00000E+00  0.0000  1.31707E-06  0.0104
10010  1.92698E-14  0.7071  1.27281E-06  0.0103
10011  4.47277E-14  0.7071  1.28429E-06  0.0106
10012  0.00000E+00  0.0000  1.27027E-06  0.0105
10013  0.00000E+00  0.0000  1.29623E-06  0.0105
10014  0.00000E+00  0.0000  1.32037E-06  0.0101
10015  0.00000E+00  0.0000  1.28948E-06  0.0105
10016  1.10023E-11  0.7053  1.33163E-06  0.0106
10017  1.74410E-11  0.5005  1.36073E-06  0.0102
10018  0.00000E+00  0.0000  1.35462E-06  0.0102
10019  1.69181E-13  0.7071  1.38641E-06  0.0102
10020  0.00000E+00  0.0000  1.33099E-06  0.0102
10021  0.00000E+00  0.0000  1.35307E-06  0.0100
10022  0.00000E+00  0.0000  1.33882E-06  0.0105
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
from pprint import pp


with open('data.txt') as f: data = f.read()
rows, val1, val2 = data.replace('\n','').split('vals')

# split into to lists
# drop 'f     7523' and convert rows to ints
rows = list(map(int, rows.split()[2:]))
val1 = val1.split()
val2 = val2.split()

# list comprehension to gather tuples from vals
# list(map(float, valX[i:i+2])) inside if you want actual floats
val1 = [val1[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(val1), 2)]
val2 = [val2[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(val2), 2)]

# zip and unpack tuples
result = [[a,*b,*c] for a,b,c in zip(rows, val1, val2)]

pp(result)
```

```
[[10001, '0.00000E+00', '0.0000', '1.34313E-06', '0.0104'],
 [10002, '7.65079E-12', '0.7071', '1.32163E-06', '0.0102'],
 [10003, '0.00000E+00', '0.0000', '1.30039E-06', '0.0105'],
 [10004, '3.87977E-14', '0.5513', '1.37575E-06', '0.0106'],
 [10005, '0.00000E+00', '0.0000', '1.30792E-06', '0.0102'],
 [10006, '0.00000E+00', '0.0000', '1.28351E-06', '0.0104'],
 [10007, '0.00000E+00', '0.0000', '1.32164E-06', '0.0102'],
 [10008, '0.00000E+00', '0.0000', '1.32969E-06', '0.0104'],
 [10009, '0.00000E+00', '0.0000', '1.31707E-06', '0.0104'],
 [10010, '1.92698E-14', '0.7071', '1.27281E-06', '0.0103'],
 [10011, '4.47277E-14', '0.7071', '1.28429E-06', '0.0106'],
 [10012, '0.00000E+00', '0.0000', '1.27027E-06', '0.0105'],
 [10013, '0.00000E+00', '0.0000', '1.29623E-06', '0.0105'],
 [10014, '0.00000E+00', '0.0000', '1.32037E-06', '0.0101'],
 [10015, '0.00000E+00', '0.0000', '1.28948E-06', '0.0105'],
 [10016, '1.10023E-11', '0.7053', '1.33163E-06', '0.0106'],
 [10017, '1.74410E-11', '0.5005', '1.36073E-06', '0.0102'],
 [10018, '0.00000E+00', '0.0000', '1.35462E-06', '0.0102'],
 [10019, '1.69181E-13', '0.7071', '1.38641E-06', '0.0102'],
 [10020, '0.00000E+00', '0.0000', '1.33099E-06', '0.0102'],
 [10021, '0.00000E+00', '0.0000', '1.35307E-06', '0.0100'],
 [10022, '0.00000E+00', '0.0000', '1.33882E-06', '0.0105']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the file line by line.

If the current line starts with `f`, you have started a new header section.  (It's not clear what you want to do with the `7523` value that is on the same line as the `f` in your example)

Otherwise if the current line starts with `vals`, you have started a new values section.

Otherwise you're in the middle of a header or values section that has already started.  Read the values from the line into a list and store them appropriately.

When the file is exhausted, print all the headers and values.